# How to iterate over and filter an array?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a program that involves filtering and folding over arrays. I've been using [*The Rust Programming Language*, first edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/iterators.html) as a reference, but I don't understand what happens when I form iterators over arrays. Here is an example:

```
fn compiles() {
    let range = (1..6);
    let range_iter = range.into_iter();
    range_iter.filter(|&x| x == 2);
}

fn does_not_compile() {
    let array = [1, 4, 3, 2, 2];
    let array_iter = array.into_iter();
    //13:34 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq<_>` is not implemented for the type `&_` [E0277]
    array_iter.filter(|&x| x == 2);
}

fn janky_workaround() {
    let array = [1, 4, 3, 2, 2];
    let array_iter = array.into_iter();
    // Note the dereference in the lambda body
    array_iter.filter(|&x| *x == 2);
}
```

([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8afca446c40e23f597b4&version=stable))

In the first function, I follow that the iterator over the range does not take ownership, so I must take a `&x` in `filter`'s lambda, but I don't understand why the second example with the array behaves differently.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In cases like this, it's very useful to force the compiler to tell you the type of the variable. Let's trigger a type error by assigning the closure argument to an incompatible type:

```rust
array_iter.filter(|x| { let _: () = x; x == 2 });
```

This fails with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:41
  |
4 |     array_iter.filter(|x| { let _: () = x; x == 2 });
  |                                    --   ^ expected `()`, found `&&{integer}`
  |                                    |
  |                                    expected due to this
```

Now we know the type of `x` is a `&&{integer}` - a reference to a reference to *some* kind of integer. We can then match against that instead:

```rust
fn hooray() {
    let array = [1, 4, 3, 2, 2];
    let array_iter = array.into_iter();
    array_iter.filter(|&&x| x == 2);
}
```

The question now becomes "why is it a reference to a reference"? The short version is that the [iterator of an array returns references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator) (see the `type Item = &'a T` part). In addition, [`Iterator::filter` passes a reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) to the closure to prevent moving and subsequently losing non-`Copy` types.

In Rust 1.51, you can use [`array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html) to get a by-value iterator:

```rust
fn hooray() {
    let array = [1, 4, 3, 2, 2];
    let array_iter = std::array::IntoIter::new(array);
    array_iter.filter(|&x| x == 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I picked this answer because it walked me through how I might have used the compiler to figure it out on my own. I also appreciated the links to learn more.

Answer (score 37):

Arrays are the type `[T; N]` in Rust, for any element type `T` and a constant number `N`. It's a fixed size array.

Rust doesn't implement [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) for arrays at the moment. All arrays coerce to slices (type `[T]`) and the slice methods are available on the array because of this. The arrays also get the slice's iterator, which is called `std::slice::Iter<'a, T>` and has elements of type `&'a T`: it iterates by reference!

This is why `into_iter()` on a `Range<i32>` produces an iterator of `i32` and `into_iter()` on a `[i32; 5]` produces an iterator of `&i32`.

If you need by value iterators for arrays and

- You are using Rust 1.51 or newer, you can use [`array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html):

  ```rust
  fn does_now_compile() {
      let array = [1, 4, 3, 2, 2];
      let array_iter = std::array::IntoIter::new(array);
      array_iter.filter(|&x| x == 2);
  }
  ```
- You are using older versions of Rust, by-value iterators have been implemented in the broader ecosystem, see [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) and [literator](https://github.com/kmcallister/literator).

Answer (score 3):

As Shepmaster and bluss said, you can check the [documentation for the array type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html), which mentions:

> Arrays of sizes from 0 to 32 (inclusive) implement the following
>   traits if the element type allows it:
>
> - `IntoIterator` (implemented for `&[T; N]` and `&mut [T; N]`)

As it says, this is only for references, and is reflected in its `Item` type: `type Item = &'a T` and `type Item = &'a mut T`.

Comment: The maximum length of 32 is generally lifted as of [Rust 1.47](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.47.0/RELEASES.md#libraries).