# How to take ownership of a value in flat_map

Tags: iterator, rust

With the following simplified/abstracted version of my problem:

```
fn main() {
    let foo_selectors = vec![0, 1];

    let foos: Vec<_> = foo_selectors
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|i| get_foo(i).into_iter())
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", foos);
}

fn get_foo(i: u8) -> [u8; 3] {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        [1, 2, 3]
    } else {
        [4, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9073a983a386f717184fb29d609e37b5&version=stable)

I get the following error message:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:6:44
   |
6  |         .flat_map(|i| get_foo(i).into_iter())
   |                       ----------           ^ temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |                       |
   |                       temporary value created here
...
10 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
```

The error message complains about borrowing, but I've used `into_iter` everywhere, which as I understand it, takes ownership of the iterated values. I want to take ownership of the values returned from `get_foo` and insert their elements into `foos`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to take ownership of a value in flat_map

There's nothing special about `flat_map` here. When calling `get_foo`, ownership of the return value is transferred to the caller, just like anywhere else in Rust.

> I've used into_iter everywhere, which as I understand it, takes ownership of the iterated values.

Usually, yes, but not for an array. See the linked questions below for why. This is the source of the problem. The `flat_map` closure owns the result of `get_foo`, and then you *take a reference to it*. The reference cannot live beyond the closure, but that's what you are asking it to do.

As a workaround, you can return a `Vec` from your function:

```
fn get_foo(i: u8) -> Vec<u8> {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        vec![1, 2, 3]
    } else {
        vec![4, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

You could also convert the returned array into a `Vec` inside the `flat_map` call.

If you felt like the situation warranted it, you could implement your own iterator:

```
struct CloneArrayIter<T> {
    arr: [T; 3],
    idx: usize,
}

impl<T> CloneArrayIter<T> {
    fn new(arr: [T; 3]) -> Self {
        Self { arr, idx: 0 }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for CloneArrayIter<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.idx < 3 {
            let value = self.arr[self.idx].clone();
            self.idx += 1;
            Some(value)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

And use it as `.flat_map(|i| CloneArrayIter::new(get_foo(i)))`

I'd probably just use an `ArrayVec` from [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) though:

```
extern crate arrayvec;

use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

fn main() {
    let foo_selectors = vec![0, 1];

    let foos: Vec<_> = foo_selectors
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|i| get_foo(i))
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", foos);
}

fn get_foo(i: u8) -> ArrayVec<[u8; 3]> {
    if i % 2 == 0 { [1, 2, 3] } else { [4, 5, 6] }.into()
}
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)
- [How to Iterate Over an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30467085/155423)