# What type signature to use for an iterator generated from a slice?

Tags: rust

I have this toy example, but it's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
fn lazy_vec() {
    let vec: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = i64>> = Box::new(vec.into_iter());
    iter = Box::new(iter.map(|x| x + 1));
    // potentially do additional similar transformations to iter
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

This (if I'm not mistaken) is a lazy iterator pattern, and the actual `map` operation doesn't occur until `.collect()` is called. I want to do the same thing with slices:

```
fn lazy_slice() {
    let vec: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let slice: &[i64] = &vec[..3];
    let mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = i64>> = Box::new(slice.into_iter());
    iter = Box::new(iter.map(|x| x + 1));
    // potentially do additional similar transformations to iter
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

This results in a type mismatch:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, i64> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == i64`
 --> src/main.rs:4:47
  |
4 |     let mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = i64>> = Box::new(slice.into_iter());
  |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found i64
  |
  = note: expected type `&i64`
             found type `i64`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::iter::Iterator<Item=i64>`
```

I can't figure out what I need to do to resolve this error. The second `note` made me think I needed:

```
iter = Box::new(iter.map(|x| x + 1) as Iterator<Item = i64>);
```

or

```
iter = Box::new(iter.map(|x| x + 1)) as Box<Iterator<Item = i64>>;
```

These fail with other errors depending on the exact syntax (e.g. `expected reference, found i64`, or `expected i64, found &i64`). I've tried other ways to declare the types involved, but I'm basically just blindly adding `&` and `*` in places and not making any progress.

What am I missing here? What do I need to change in order to make this compile?

---

**Edit**

Here's a slightly more concrete example - I need `iter` to be `mut` so that I can compose an unknown number of such transformations before actually invoking `.collect()`. My impression was this was a somewhat common pattern, apologies if that wasn't correct.

```
fn lazy_vec(n: i64) {
    let vec: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = i64>> = Box::new(vec.into_iter());
    for _ in 0..n {
        iter = Box::new(iter.map(|x| x + 1));
    }
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

I'm aware I could rewrite this specific task in a simpler way (e.g. a single `map` that adds `n` to each element) - it's an oversimplified MCVE of the problem I'm running into. My issue is this works for `lazy_vec`, but I'm not sure how to do the same with slices.

---

**Edit 2**

I'm just learning Rust and some of the nomenclature and concepts are new to me. Here's what I'm envisioning doing in Python, for comparison. My intent is to do the same thing with slices that I can currently do with vectors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import itertools

ls = [i for i in range(10)]

def lazy_work(input):
  for i in range(10):
    input = (i + 1 for i in input)
  # at this point no actual work has been done
  return input

print("From list: %s" % list(lazy_work(ls)))
print("From slice: %s" % list(lazy_work(itertools.islice(ls, 5))))
```

Obviously in Python there's no issues with typing, but hopefully that more clearly demonstrates my intent?

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423) and [How to iterate over an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30467085/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster added more detail, hopefully that makes it clearer? My instructor shared the `Box<Iterator<_>>` pattern for vectors, so that's what I was starting with. If there are alternate approaches to lazy composition I'd be interested to hear about them.

Comment: The issue is a type mismatch. The result of a `.map` is an iterator for values, but you have references, so you _have_ to assign to a new variable somewhere since you need a variable that has the proper type. Did you consider something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dcd6a5f7f2141888fbdcec7fb18c00e6&version=stable ?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yep, I realize it's a type problem - hence the question :) your suggestion looks promising! I'll give it a try, do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Nah, the other answers pretty much cover it already.

Comment: @downvoter I'd very much appreciate feedback about how I could have made this question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423), these methods create iterators which yield different types when called on a `Vec` compared to a slice.

[`[T]::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) and [`[T]::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.into_iter) both return an iterator [which yields values of type `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator). That means that the returned value doesn't implement `Iterator<Item = i64>` but instead  `Iterator<Item = &i64>`, as the error message states.

However, your subsequent `map` statements *change* the type of the iterator's item to an `i64`, which means the type of the iterator would also need to change. As an analogy, you've essentially attempted this:

```
let mut a: &i64 = &42;
a = 99;
```

[`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) exists to make clones of the iterated value. In this case, it converts a `&i64` to an `i64` essentially dereferencing the value:

```
fn lazy_slice(n: i64) {
    let array = [1i64, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut iter: Box<Iterator<Item = i64>> = Box::new(array.iter().cloned());
    for _ in 0..n {
        iter = Box::new(iter.map(|x| x + 1));
    }
    println!("{:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `cloned()` will actually copy the contents, correct? That would introduce an O(n) memory and time overhead.

Comment: @dimo414 what do you mean by "overhead"? What do you think happens when you add a reference to a number with another number? The reference is dereferenced and then the value can be added. When you call `cloned`, the dereference only happens as an explicit earlier step as that's the implementation of `Clone` for `&i64`. What extra time or memory do you believe is required? You are already aware that iterators are lazy, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure what all the semantics are in Rust, I'm still learning :) My understanding was `cloned()` introduces overhead by copying everything being cloned, and I'm trying to avoid introducing more overhead when using a slice of a vector vs. just using the full vector itself. If `.cloned()` on iterators is actually effectively free that's good to know.

Comment: @dimo414 `.clone()` can be heavy *when you're cloning heavy things*. Here, you're cloning an integer -- the only thing for `clone()` to do is dereference it, which you have to do anyway. When you clone a `Box<Vec<[i64; 1000]>>`, yes, that's a "deep" copy.

Comment: @dimo414 Calling it "overhead" is... misleading at best. Overhead is work you need to do that doesn't directly contribute to your goal. If you have a reference to an integer, you have to dereference it before you can do math on it anyway. You *do* have overhead in your examples because you create a `Vec` that is never used other than to slice from, but I assume that's from the MCVE. In your original function, you take ownership of the `Vec` and iterate directly on the values from it, so there's no need to dereference them the first time.

Comment: Thanks. I think my confusion stemmed from the error message saying `expected type '&i64' found type 'i64'` - I read that as saying the type returned from `slice.into_iter()` was an iterator of `i64`. It seems the "found type" it's referring to is the declared type while the "expected type" is the type of the expression.