# String equality in Rust: how does referencing and dereferencing work?

Tags: string, rust, dereference, borrowing

As a Rust newbie, I'm working through the [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) problems to help me get a feel for the language. Problem 4 deals with palindromes, and I found two solutions for creating a vector of palindromes, but I'm not sure how either of them work.

I'm using a vector of strings, `products`, that's calculated like this:

```
let mut products = Vec::new();
for i in 100..500 {
    for j in 500..1000 {
        products.push((i * j).to_string());
    }
}
```

For filtering these products to only those that are palindromic, I have the following two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
let palindromes: Vec<_> = products
    .iter()
    .filter(|&x| x == &x.chars().rev().collect::<String>())
    .collect();
```

**Solution 2:**

```
let palindromes: Vec<_> = products
    .iter()
    .filter(|&x| *x == *x.chars().rev().collect::<String>())
    .collect();
```

They both yield the correct result, but I have no idea why!

In Solution 1, we're comparing a reference of a string to a reference of a string we've just created?

In Solution 2, we dereference a reference to a string and compare it to a dereferenced new string?

**What I would expect to be able to do:**

```
let palindromes: Vec<_> = products
    .iter()
    .filter(|x| x == x.chars().rev().collect::<String>())
    .collect();
```

I'm hoping somebody will be able to explain to me:

- What is the difference is between my two solutions, and why do they both work?
- Why can't I just use `x` without referencing or dereferencing it in my filter function?

Thank you!

Comment: "They both yield the correct result, but I have no idea why!" => "Theory is when you know everything but nothing works **practice is when everything works but no one knows why** in our lab theory and practice are combined nothing works and no one knows why"

Comment: I think this is very similar to [How to iterate over an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30467085/3650362) (poor title notwithstanding). Do the answers to that question clear things up at all?

Comment: Note that you do not need to allocate a `String`, you can compare the iterators: `.filter(|x| x.chars().eq(x.chars().rev()))`.

Comment: @piercebot Nice, Project Euler is also how I started rust. May I challenge you to come up with a palindrome check that does not require allocation (`collect` creates a new `String` on the heap)? :)

Comment: Well.. so much for challenge :p

Comment: @Boiethios I didn't know about `.eq`, this is super duper!  Thanks!  Doing it the brute-force way was a good way to run into pitfalls though; thanks @kazemakase for the lesson :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. `Vec<String>.iter()` returns an iterator over references (`&String`).
2. The closure argument of `.filter()` takes a reference to an iterator's item. So the type that is passed to the closure is a double reference `&&String`.
3. `|&x|` tells the closure to expect a reference, so `x` is now of type `&String`.

First solution: `collect` returns a `String`, of which `&` takes the reference. `x` is also a reference to a string, so the comparison is between two `&String`.

Second solution: The dereference operator `*` is applied to `x`, which results in a `String`. The right hand side is interesting: The `String` result of `collect` is dereferenced. This results in a string slice because [`String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref). Now the comparison is between `String` and `str`, which is works because it is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-PartialEq%3Cstr%3E) in the standard library (Note that `a == b` is equivalent to `a.eq(&b)`).

Third solution: The compiler explains why it does not work.

> the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<std::string::String>` is not implemented for `&&std::string::String`

The left side is a double reference to string (`&&String`) and the right side is just a `String` . **You need to get both sides to the same "reference level".** All of these work:

```
x.iter().filter(|x| x == &&x.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
x.iter().filter(|x| *x == &x.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
x.iter().filter(|x| **x == x.chars().rev().collect::<String>());
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the thorough explanation! Are all closure arguments references by default, or is it a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @piercebot Case by case. If you look at the definition of [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) you can see that it requires a closure that takes a `&Iter::Item`. In contrast, for example the closure accepted by `filter_map` takes `Iter::Item`, which is not a reference.