# Idiomatic way to filter values matching a pattern in an iterator

Tags: rust

In this below example ([here is the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20%5B-3_i32%2C%200%2C%201%2C%205%2C%20-10%5D%3B%0Aassert_eq!(*a.iter().min_by_key(%7Cx%7C%20x.abs()).unwrap()%2C%200)%3B%0A%7D&edition=2018)), I need to filter values in an iterator that match a specific pattern.

One way I found is to use a `match` returning an `Option` in `filter_map`:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
struct Entity(i32);

enum Event {
    EntityInserted(Entity),
    EntityRemoved(Entity),
}

fn main() {
    let [entity1, entity2] = [Entity(1), Entity(2)];

    let events = vec![
        Event::EntityInserted(entity1),
        Event::EntityRemoved(entity1),
        Event::EntityInserted(entity2),
    ];

    let inserted_entities: Vec<_> = events
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|event| match event {                  // <--- 
            Event::EntityInserted(entity) => Some(entity), // <--- Those lines
            _ => None,                                     // <---    here
        })                                                 // <---
        .collect();

    dbg!(inserted_entities);
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to have this behavior ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467085/how-to-iterate-over-and-filter-an-array answer your question?

Comment: If you want to filter *and unwrap* (aka return entities) then this looks idiomatic (clippy certainly doesn't complain about it). If it's a common task, then you just extract that as methods on `Event`, similar to [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) / [`Result::err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.err) but that's about it. Also for such a simple pattern `if let` can be shorter and clearer than a full-blown `match`, but that's more of a personal preference really.

Comment: @Masklinn Thanks, having something like `Result::ok` is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

As for the `filter_map`, I think that's the way to go.

Curiously, I wrote a macro yesterday that generates a `Some` in case the `if` was "successful", and otherwise evaluates to `None`:

```
macro_rules! if_then_some {
    ($cond: expr, $val: expr) => {
        if $cond { Some($val) } else { None }
    };
    (let $pattern:pat = $expr: expr, $val: expr) => {
        if let $pattern = $expr { Some($val) } else { None }
    };
}
```

As it stands, it can be used for checking `bool`-conditions and `if let`-conditions. In your case it could be used [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=509f93c20c31cbabffec140f157bdfa2):

```
let inserted_entities: Vec<_> = events
    .iter()
    .filter_map(|event|
        if_then_some!(let Event::EntityInserted(entity)=event, entity)
    )
    .collect();
```

It is disputable if this is "idiomatic", but imho it is terse yet quite readable.

*A bit off-topic:* On the other hand, whenever I see `if let` with something else than `Option` or `Result`, I am wary that the compiler does not warn me if I add new variants that should be checked in these conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) 
While I personally do not think the suggested macro is the most appropriate
solution, it shows well how the language benefits from adding syntactic sugar 
macro around pattern matching like [the `matches!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/macro.matches.html) 